# How small can I get full fledged compiler like clang or gcc in terms of size for an embedded system?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, embedded, embedded-linux

I am making an embedded linux system and for the hell of it trying to fit my secondary boot loader (AT91), U-Boot, the linux Kernel, and the rootfs onto an 8 MB data flash chip. Busybox takes up roughly 2 MB though I can probably get it down to roughly 1 MB, and U-Boot takes roughly 512 KB and that too I bet I can get smaller.

Can I decrease the size of these larger compilers by cross compiling on my desktop and take out code like things meant for optimization passes and building code for handling all architectures except armv5te? Or am I stuck with the 50+ MB binaries for gcc? If there is no hope of getting it in under 6 MB, what's the smallest I can get?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an appropriate site for this sort of question.

Comment: Why would anyone know the answer to that question without trying it?   Google to see if someone has done it, and if not, try it yourself.

Comment: It seemed like the best one out of Linux/Unix and chiphacker and stackoverflow was here, but if you know where it would better fit let me know and I would be happy to post there.

Comment: @DaleWilson That's the thing, I don't know how to try it myself, hence the question. And, maybe my google fu is failing me, but I can't seem to find anything regarding how to make gcc or clang themselves smaller by removing unneeded arch support and whatnot.

Comment: @hak8or I don't know of an appropriate place (but the question doesn't seem too obscure that there isn't one). It's just that SO is for help with well defined narrowly scoped programming problems and what you're asking, while loosely a programming problem (relating to a tool), is really broad rather than well defined, narrowly scoped.

Comment: On my Debian/x86-66 desktop `g++` is mostly `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/cc1plus` which is 17Mbytes -but you need the C++ headers `/usr/include/c++/4.9/` for 9Mbytes.

Comment: Why can't you *cross-compile* the executables for your tiny ARM system ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I totally can just cross compile, but I want to learn how to do this instead as an educational exercise for fun. I designed and built this system myself, I figure a cool next step would have it be able to compile my own code on itself.

Comment: At my shop, we extracted the compiler (language interpreter) out of the embedded system for speed and data purposes.  The language files are compiled into data tables and the tables downloaded into the embedded systems.  This was a good move, since now the customers have expanded on the language requirements and are considering an IDE.

Comment: If you want to develop a compiler as an educational project, I highly recommend using a desktop platform, as developing for an embedded system is more difficult (remote debugging, fixed and small constrained memory, etc).  I still push for people to develop the modules on the PC then incorporate them into the embedded environment.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks for the suggestion! Though, I am not trying to make my own compiler. I am trying to take out as much from GCC or clang as possible so I can fit it onto my embedded system and then compile very basic projects, like a hello world, or my school assignments. I wouldn't be actually developing on the system.

Comment: Why do you need the compiler on the target?

Comment: @Clifford As I said earlier, I want to since I think it would be cool to have a system I made be able to compile code I made. A learning exercise, for fun, because I want to.

Comment: @hak8or : You may have said that earlier in a comment, but such information should be in the question.  You should respond to comments about your question by improving the question rather than entering into a dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at some alternative compilers; gcc isn't known for being small. In particular, you may be interested in [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/), the Tiny C Compiler. :)

Comment: Thanks! I've actually looked at this before but I am worried about it not being under development for the past few years and not supporting C++, hence me wanting to try and get clang and gcc smaller. Though if I can't get those two small enough, I will probably stick with TCC.

Comment: @duskwuff do you think your post qualifies more as an answer or a comment?

Comment: However, TinyCC  produces very fat and very slow binary code.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Smaller C](https://github.com/alexfru/SmallerC). It's comparable to TCC, though supports less of the language. We run it on [RetroBSD](http://retrobsd.org/wiki/doku.php) in 96KB of RAM.